# SSIS : Excel Source detection type

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

i'm currently working

- in sql server 2012,
- and OLEDB JET provider 12.0.
- excel 13.

i have to import many excel files ... but this bloody provider doesn't detect the rigth type in a very wierd and strange way, meaning ==>

i know for the rowtypeguess that scans the 8 first lines to determine the type(but i can't change the register to change that property in all the servers) .

and the big  problem is that ssis detects some float columns as dt-wstr because they have the first eigth at null but for others he detects the right type : float !

i don't understand why there is an invariant behavior !!!

i have even tried to force the excel columns to numbers but still SSIS want them to be DT_WSTR.

so i'm forced to do a tmp table and then convert all the columns that need to be float like this :

```
case 
            when isnull([cola],'') <> ''  
            then cast(replace([cola],',','.') as float) 
end
```

the problem is that i have countless columns and i have to do this integration prety frenquently : so it means that if the next time these columns are suddenly recognized as floats but other are no longer recognized as floats 
i have to change every thing at every integration.

how can i manage that for the long run ? have you some kind of explanations?

Comment: Import everything as strings (or unicode strings) and then put a Data Conversion task between the Source and Destination.

Comment: Are you building a persistent SSIS package, or are you using the import wizard?

Comment: @TabAlleman no it's a persistent package

Comment: What steps did you take exactly, when you " tried to force the excel columns to numbers"?

Comment: @digital.aaron how to import everything into string directly, is there a simple manipulation or do I have to force data conversion with the component for the 1000columns to string? ( new to ssis )

Comment: You have 1000 columns in your Excel file? You have a much bigger problem than just datatype conversion, IMO.

Comment: @digital.aaron no but 1000 columns in 4 excel files --> 250 each roughly

Comment: @TabAlleman to force it : I got to excel I select  the column (A for exemple) and put the type to number with x decimals

Comment: From experience you will *never* get this to work cleanly. A long time ago I wrote some code to process excel files in C# and never looked back. Or if you can get them as csv you can do it all in sql server stored procs directly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so like i said in my question, 
i have even tried to force the excel columns to numbers like following [image: image to show how i do it]

and today restarting my computer, i noticed he was detecting them as floats !!!! hallelouiahhhhhhhh

during the afternoon they went back to wstr ... harsh life i get i will have to force everything to wstr and thennnnn convert them one by one ...for countless cols ....

i'm wondering what's the point with ssis ... ? it's not practical at all !!!